# Sums over the entries of eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian

Consider the Laplacian of a general graph,

$$
L = D - A
$$
where $D$ is the degree matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix.
Its eigenvectors are defined by

$$
L\mathbf{u}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{u}_i.
$$

Because $L$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, the eigenvectors are real and orthonormal,

$$
\sum_k (\mathbf{u}_i)_k (\mathbf{u}_j)_k = \delta_{ij}.
$$

I am wondering if something can be said about more complicated sums over
the entries of the eigenvectors. In particular, I have some numerical experiments that suggest that most of the entries in

$$
\sum_k (\mathbf{u}_i)_k (\mathbf{u}_j)_k (\mathbf{u}_\ell)_k (\mathbf{u}_m)_k 
$$

are zero for generic graphs. Is it possible to find an expression for that sum?

Comment: Why not use $U^\top U = I$? Why complicate?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo how would you write my second expression in that form? I couldn't come up with a way so I used vector component notation.

Comment: You can multiply each vector by the $k$-th vector of the standard basis, thereby obtaining the $k$-th entry.

Comment: Not gonna be pretty. In fact, for the second expression it does not bring you much.